# Android: change submenu parent text size

Tags: android, menu, size, navigation-drawer

I have this menu structure for my navigation view:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_clients"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_group"
        android:title="@string/nav_clients"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_products"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_box"
        android:title="@string/nav_products" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_orders"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_buy"
        android:title="@string/nav_orders" />

</group>

<item android:title="@string/nav_title_app">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black"
            android:title="@string/nav_settings" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sync"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_sync_black"
            android:title="@string/nav_sync" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

I have succeeded to change the menu items text size, but only the item which contains a menu didn't changed the size?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found any official way of doing so, neither by style, but you can achieve it programmatically, take a look below.

```
private void setMenuHeadTitleSize(int itemId) {

    Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(itemId);

    MenuItem subMenuItem = menuItem.getSubMenu().getItem();
    String title = String.valueOf(subMenuItem.getTitle());

    SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(title);
    mNewTitle.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.1f), 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    subMenuItem.setTitle(mNewTitle);
}
```

Also give an Id to your SubMenu item

```
<item android:id="@+id/nav_top"
    android:title="@string/nav_title_app">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black"
            android:title="@string/nav_settings" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sync"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_sync_black"
            android:title="@string/nav_sync" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

and finally, once NavigationView is inflated, and the menu attached, call the function above

```
setMenuHeadTitleSize(R.id.nav_top);
```